# How do I display an Node response object in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http

I have created a Javascript file which uses twit(npm) to get a stream of tweets based on certain rules to retrieve tweets in real time

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const open = require('open');
const franc = require('franc')


const apikey = 'XXX'
const apiSecretKey = 'XXX'
const accessToken = 'XXX'
const accessTokenSecret = 'XXX'

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         apikey,
  consumer_secret:      apiSecretKey,
  access_token:         accessToken,
  access_token_secret:  accessTokenSecret,
});

( function getTweets() {

    // //1. GET RECENT TWEETS
     //T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#tesla since:2020-04-15', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
    //   const tweets = data.statuses
    //   // .map(tweet => `LANG: ${franc(tweet.text)} : ${tweet.text}`) //CHECK LANGUAGE
    //   .map(tweet => tweet.text)
    //   .filter(tweet => tweet.toLowerCase().includes('elon'));
    //   console.log(tweets);
    // })

    // //2. REAL TIME MONITORING USING STREAM (HASHTAG)
     var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#travel' })
     stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
         console.log(tweet.text);
         console.log('Language: ' + franc(tweet.text));
         console.log('------');
     })

    // 3. REAL TIME MONITORING USING STREAM (LOCATION)
    //var sanFrancisco = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]
    //var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: sanFrancisco })
    
    //SHOW NOTIFICATION FOR EACH RECEIVED TWEET
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      console.log(tweet.text);
      let url = `https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`

      notifier.notify({
        title: tweet.user.name,
        message: tweet.text
      });

      notifier.on('click', async function(notifierObject, options, event) {
        console.log('clicked');
        await open(url);
      });
    })
})();
```

My issue is that I want to take the returned objects, and display it on a standalone page in my react app. I have tried wrapping this code in a component, but I am having no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Twit works and I have only tested a little React, but I would try the following:

Define

```js
function getTweets() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#travel' }).on('tweet', resolve);       
    });
}
```

and then use

```
let tweets = await getTweets();
```

inside the React component code.